# Mathematica exportation faeled

Tags: export, wolfram-mathematica

Hello i'm new of this forum and new user of mathematica.

I used this sintax

```
Export[PathToSave <> "Frq-" <> NameToSave <> ".xls", frq]
```

in two different file but in one case it works and export my xls file, in another case i have this error:

```
StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in C:\.......-<>NameToSave<>.xls. >>
StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in C:\.......-<>NameToSave<>.xls. >>
Export::chtype: First argument C:\.......-<>NameToSave<>.xls is not a valid file specification. >>
```

dots are instead of my path.

I checked so many times the path to the directory and files but the error doesn't disappear.

Could somebody help me?

thanks.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of the following: FullForm[PathToSave<>"Frq-"<>NameToSave<>".xls"] and Short[frq] that are done immediately before the case that does not work. I am hoping that one or the other of those will help expose the problem.

Comment: the error indicates the symbol `NameToSave` has not been assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Check what type of *atomic expression* is `NameToSave`. For example if `NameToSave` is an *Integer* you should convert it to a string using `ToSting[NameToSave]`.

You can use `Head[NameToSave]` to check what type of atomic expression is `NameToSave`.